# How can I add an additional working IP to a VM?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, proxmox, hetzner, yaml

I have 2 websites working fine on the same IP (92.46.87.48). Is a ubuntu server on a VM. Now I need to assign one ip for every website. I edit the /etc/hosts fine, I just buy an additional IP and now I need to config the network.
All servers are working fine, I just can't reach the new IP (92.46.87.15). With my actual config, If i ping, I recieve the "pong" only from the same machine (92.46.87.48). No ping from outside.

"**PROXMOX DEBIAN SERVER**" IP = **92.46.87.52** (only 1 VM with 2 IPs)

"**VM UBUNTU 22 SERVER**" IP = **92.46.87.48**  (subnet 92.46.87.48/27)

```
Gateway:    92.46.87.33 
Netmask:    255.255.255.224
```

"**VM UBUNTU 22 SERVER**" **ADDITIONAL IP** = **92.46.87.15** (subnet 92.46.87.15/27)

```
Gateway:    92.46.87.1
Netmask:    255.255.255.224
```

---

"PROXMOX SERVER" /etc/network/interface

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 92.46.87.52/27
        gateway 92.46.87.33
        bridge-ports eno1
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        up ip route add 92.46.87.15 dev vmbr0
        
        #Kvm bridged mode TCP/IP network performance fix (hardware hangup)
        pre-up /sbin/ethtool --offload eno1 gso off tso off sg off gro off
```

---

"PROXMOX SERVER" route -n  (NO PING TO THE NEW ADDITIONAL IP)

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         92.46.87.33     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vmbr0
92.46.87.32     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 vmbr0
```

"PROXMOX SERVER": **ip route add 92.46.87.15 dev vmbr0**

"PROXMOX SERVER (ping ok now)" ping 92.46.87.15

```
64 bytes from 92.46.87.15: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.259 ms
```

"PROXMOX SERVER" route -n

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         92.46.87.33     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vmbr0
92.46.87.15     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 vmbr0
92.46.87.32     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 vmbr0
```

---

"PROXMOX SERVER" ip addr show vmbr0

```
3: vmbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:36:bc:29:89:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 92.46.87.52/27 scope global vmbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

"UBUNTU SERVER" /etc/network/interface

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
    
auto lo
iface lo inet lookback

auto ens18
iface ens18 inet static
        address 00:50:56:00:35:D3
        gateway 92.46.87.33
```

---

"UBUNTU SERVER" /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

```
network:
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      optional: true
      addresses:
        - 92.46.87.48/27
        - 92.46.87.15/27
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 92.46.87.33
          metric: 100
          on-link: true
  version: 2
```

---

"UBUNTU SERVER" ip a

```
2: ens18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:00:35:d3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s18
    inet 92.46.87.48/27 brd 92.46.87.63 scope global ens18
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 92.46.87.15/27 brd 92.46.87.31 scope global ens18
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

"UBUNTU SERVER" route -n

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         92.46.87.33     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens18
92.46.87.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 ens18
92.46.87.32     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 ens18
```

---

"UBUNTU SERVER" ping 92.46.87.15

```
64 bytes from 92.46.87.15: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.007 ms
```

---

So, what do you think guys? What is the reason that I can't reach 92.46.87.15 from outside? Thank you!

Comment: The additional IP address is in different subnet than the original IP address. `92.46.87.15` is in `92.46.87.0/27` subnet and `92.46.87.48` is in `92.46.87.32/27` subnet. Having two different subnet IP addresses on same interface doesn't sound right. However, without knowledge of the provider's network setup this is difficult to diagnose. Please double-check your provider documentation and ask help from their support.

Comment: Indeed, such kind of question should always come along with the host provider's name and a link to its documentation on how to use multiple addresses (each provider has its own quirk).

Comment: *Now I need to assign one ip for every website* - Why? Named based vhosts has been a thing for quite a while.

Comment: Tell us if the packet is making it to 92.46.87.1.

Comment: @GregAskew there is no response pinging that gateway.

Comment: If you cannot even communicate with the router, why even bother adding the remaining 80% of the information? The question should be "I'm configuring a network adapter and cannot communicate with the router. How do I do that".

Comment: Thank you @GregAskew . I just open a ticket on Hetzner and ask them. I think that I set a bad config or something.

Comment: They said is normal that I don't have any reply from pinging that gateway.

Comment: From the provider in comment: https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/ip/additional-ip-adresses/#additional-addresses . single IP address and subnet IP addresses are not handled the same: other gateway versus same gateway. The two-gateways case with a single additional IP address can lead to a multihomed system situation. It's not clear to me what owns what and does what in the current setup.

Comment: As ARP is needed for connectivity, `arping` should succeed even if ping won't. Try this on Ubuntu: `arping -s 92.46.87.15 92.46.87.1`. If this gets an answer, then I guess it's a multi-homed case for the Ubuntu VM. Actually the doc is not very clear.

Comment: There's also this part which I don't know if it applies: "Therefore you must give each individual IP address a virtual MAC address, which you can do on [Robot](https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/general/overview). " It appears one can use routing or bridging, I don't know if one can change from one method to an other without other setups (Robot ...). See also: https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/network/net-config-debian-ubuntu and https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-proxmox_ve .

Comment: @A.B , I even try setting 2 mac addresses and nothing. OK this is the arping reply: arping: Weird MAC addr 92.46.87.15

Comment: Use the other implementation of arping (iputils-arping rather than arping). That would be -S instead of -s on your implementation. Anyway you have documentation to read and possibly information to provide back (in the question rather than comments). If you need a separate MAC address (declared using "Robot"), then you can't use the same interface for the 2 IP addresses. etc.

Answer (score 0):

When ping fails and you don’t know why, you should try traceroute next. From the Windows command prompt type “tracert” followed by a space and your desired IP address and the Enter key. You should see a list of “hops” that the packet takes on its way to your specified direction.

Errors you may get include “timeout” (no response) which indicates a bad connection somewhere, and “no route” which means things are not configured properly.

Also check your firewall restrictions.

Comment: Yes, "things are not configured properly", thats why I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. On Hetzer if you config the "**Bridged Network**" you have:

> **IP addresses from additional subnets can only be used on the host system or on a single VM with a single IP**

The solution must be the "**Routed Network**"

> **Multiple single IP addresses and subnets can be used on one VM.**

So I tried to configure multiple IPs on bridge network..